# C# reads text file line as empty lines

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

**The code:**

```
public static void Read()
{
    StreamReader DBF = new StreamReader(path);
    string line;
    while ((line = DBF.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">", line);
    }
    DBF.Close();
}
```

**The file content:**

```
|_-|-_|
text
```

**The output:**

```
>
>
```

I tried also declare charset, its doesn't help:

```
StreamReader DBF = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Text file has UTF-8 charset and uses CRLF.
Why does C# reads strings from file as empty strings? Program read file properly once before.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(">" + line);` since in your code `Console.WriteLine(">", line)` `">"` specifies *format*

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($">{line}")` rather, disregards, accidentally using wrong overload instead of concatenating strings sounds like a typo to me.

Comment: You could always view the value of `line` in the debugger - this will help narrow down whether the problem is _reading_ the file or _writing_ to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your current implementation

```
Console.WriteLine(">", line);
```

`">"` means *format*; see [Console.WriteLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_) for details. You can either turn `">"` into a format string, e.g. `">{0}"`, note *placeholder* `{0}` - position where 0th argument (which is`line`) will be placed:

```
Console.WriteLine(">{0}", line);
```

Or get rid of format at all:

```
Console.WriteLine(">" + line);
```